# ブロック参照を分解すると例外（eCannotExplodeEntity）発生

Tags: .net, vb.net, ijcad

あるブロック参照を分解しようとすると例外（eCannotExplodeEntity）が発生します。
その当該ブロック参照のブロック定義のプロパティ（BlockTableRecordのExplodable）を確認しても分解可能状態（Explodable=True）でした。

例外が発生する原因について情報提供いただけると助かります。

以下はブロック分解のソースコードです。

```
Dim retIds As New ObjectIdCollection()
If blkRefId = ObjectId.Null Then Return retIds

'挿入図形を分解、削除する
Using trans As Transaction = blkRefId.Database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()
    Try
        Dim blkRef As BlockReference = TryCast(trans.GetObject(blkRefId, OpenMode.ForWrite), BlockReference)
        If blkRef IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim mdlSpcId As ObjectId = SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(blkRefId.Database)
            Dim modelSpace As BlockTableRecord = trans.GetObject(mdlSpcId, OpenMode.ForWrite)

            Dim entitySet As New DBObjectCollection()
            blkRef.Explode(entitySet)'-->ここで例外発生

            '分解後の要素を取得
            For Each dbObj As DBObject In entitySet
                Dim ent As Entity = dbObj
                retIds.Add(modelSpace.AppendEntity(ent))
                trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(ent, True)
            Next
        End If

        trans.Commit()

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        trans.Abort()
        Return New ObjectIdCollection()

    End Try

End Using

'ブロック参照は削除
IcadEntity_Delete(blkRefId)

Return retIds
```

開発環境はVisual Staudio VB.net、IJCAD2016です。

Comment: 当該ブロック参照のブロック定義を確認したところ、何も図形要素等が入っていない空のブロック定義でした。「For Each eachId As ObjectId In BlockTableRecord」等でブロック定義内の図形をカウントして空のブロック定義かどうか判定を追加しました。ちなみに構成要素が何もない空のブロック定義かどうか判断できるようなプロパティは存在しますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

何かしらの要素を含むブロック定義を元にしたブロック参照の場合、BoundsプロパティでExtents3dオブジェクトが返され、空のブロック定義を元にしたブロック参照の場合は、Boundsプロパティはnullを返します。
Boundsプロパティがnullかどうかを確認することで、ブロックが空かどうかを確認できると思います。